# PHP/Javascript validation works partially

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have Javascript/Ajax and PHP validation for my form. It's displays the errors if the form filled incorrectly, but it won't work and let me submit the form even if there is no errors.   Basically ,when I click the submit button it stays at the same page and won't do anything. 
In console I got the next error on submit: Failed to load file:///C:/Users/ilona/Desktop/BootstrapLandinPage/send.php: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https. jquery-2.2.4.min.js:4. I run my project on XAMPP.

My HTML:

```
<section class="inspiration" id="three">
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <article class="col-md-12 text-center">
                            <div class="intermediate-container">
                                <div class="heading">
                                    <h2>יש לכם שאלה? צרו איתי קשר</h2>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3"></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 center-block col-sm-6 ">
                                        <form id="mc-form" method="POST">
                                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 ">
                                                <label for="name" hidden>שם פרטי</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="cv form-control" placeholder="שם פרטי">
                                                <span class='error-message' id='name-error'></span>

                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 ">
                                                <label for="phone" hidden>טלפון</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="cv form-control" placeholder="טלפון">
                                                <span class='error-message' id='phone-error'></span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 ">
                                                <label for="email" hidden>דואר אלקטרוני</label>
                                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="cv form-control" placeholder="דואר אלקטרוני">
                                                <span class='error-message' id='email-error'></span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 ">
                                                <label for="subject" hidden>נושא</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="cv form-control" placeholder="נושא">
                                                <span class='error-message' id='subject-error'></span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 ">
                                                <label for="message" hidden>הודעה</label>
                                                <textarea name="message" id="message" class="cv form-control message" placeholder="השאירו את הודעתכם פה" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
                                                <span class='error-message' id='message-error'></span>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- <input type="submit" id="submit-button" class="btn btn-custom-outline " value="שלח" > -->
                                            <button class="btn btn-custom-outline " id="submit-button">שלח</button>
                                            <span class='error-message' id='submit-error'></span>
                                            <span class="success">Thank's for submitting the form</span>

                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- [/CONTACT] -->



        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/validateform.js" ></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
```

My validateform.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        function jsShow(id) {
            $('#'+id).show();
        }

        function jsHide(id) {
            $('#'+id).hide();
        }

        function producePrompt(message, promptLocation, color) {

            $('#'+promptLocation).text(message).css('color', color).show();

        }

        jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zא-ת]+(\s[a-zא-ת]+)*$/i.test(value);
        }, "Letters only please");
        jQuery.validator.addMethod("digitsonly", function(value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /([0-9\s\-]{7,})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?$/.test(value);
        }, "Include only digits| min :8 ");

        $('.success').hide();

        $("#mc-form").validate({
            error: function(label) {
                $(this).addClass( "error" );
            },
            rules: {
                name: {
                    required: true,
                    lettersonly: true
                },
                phone: {
                    required: true,
                    digitsonly: true
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                subject: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                message: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                }
            },
            messages: {
                name: {
                    required: "Please specify your name",
                    lettersonly: "Letters only please"
                },
                phone: {
                    required: "Phone number is required",
                    digitsonly: "Include only digits| min :8 "
                },
                email: {
                    required: "Email is required",
                    email: "Email Invalid"
                },
                subject: {
                    required: "Subject is required"
                },
                message: {
                    required: "Message is required"
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                sendForm();
            }
        });

        function sendForm() {

            $('[id*="-error"]').text(''); // default hide all error messages

            event.preventDefault(); // prevent form submission and therefore page reload

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: './send.php',
                data: $("#mc-form").serialize(),
                success: function(data) {

                    if(data.hasOwnProperty('error')) {

                        Object.keys(data['error']).forEach(function(key) {
                            producePrompt(data['error'][key], key+'-error', 'red');
                        });

                    }
                    if(data.hasOwnProperty('mail_error')) {
                        alert('Could not send mail');
                    }
                    if(data.hasOwnProperty('success')) {
                        $('.success').show();
                    }
                }
            });

        }

    });
```

My send.php:

```
$error_msg = array();
$success_msg = array();
$data = '';

// prevent warnings or errors from displaying, else you won't get proper json result
ini_set('display_errors',0);

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $error_msg['name'] = "Name is required";
    } else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Zא-ת ]*$/",$name)) {
            $error_msg['name'] = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        }
    }


    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $error_msg['email'] = "Email is required";
    } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $error_msg['email'] = "Invalid email format";
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
        $error_msg['phone'] = "Phone is required";
    } else {
        $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!preg_match("/^(\d[\s-]?)?[\(\[\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\)\]\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$/i",$phone)) {
            $error_msg['phone'] = "Invalid phone number";
        }
    }
    if (empty($_POST["subject"])) {
        $error_msg['subject'] = "Subject is required";
    }
    if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
        $error_msg['message'] = "Message is required";
    }

    if (empty($_POST["subject"])) {
        $subject = "";
    } else {
        $subject = test_input($_POST["subject"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
        $message = "";
    } else {
        $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
    }

    if (empty($error_msg)){ // note that $lastname_error does not exists
        $message_body = '';
        unset($_POST['submit']);
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
            $message_body .=  "$key: $value\n";
        }

        $to = 'xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com';
        $subjectm = 'Contact Form Submit';
        if (mail($to, $subjectm, $message)){
            $success_msg = "Message sent, thank you for contacting us!";
            $name = $email = $phone = $message = $subject = '';
        } else {
            $mail_error_msg = 'Could not send email';
        }


    }

    // set output data accordingly
    if(!empty($success_msg)) {
        $data = array('success'=>$error_msg);
    } else if(!empty($error_msg)) {
        $data = array('error'=>$error_msg);
    } else if(!empty($mail_error_msg)) {
        $data = array('mail_error'=>$mail_error_msg);
    }

    // output json that you can parse with jquery
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
}

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: you are not using wamps you are opening the file directly in your browser over the file protocol which doesn't accept ajax request

Comment: what do you mean? I am not sure what is wamps , I use XAMPP.I opening my project by clicking on index.html . Is there a different way to open it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are opening the file directly unless you configured it in Apache. The file seems to not have connection to your web server XAMPP.

You need to do following:

1. Copy `BootstrapLandinPage` directory to `c:/xampp/htdocs`
2. Add virtual host to XAMPP

Open the file `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` and add this snippet, adapted to your environment.

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.2:80>
    ServerName playground.localhost
    ServerAlias playground.localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/xampp/htdocs/your_website
    <Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/your_website/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

3. Restart Apache in control panel of XAMPP (click XAMPP icon in bottem right in Windows)
4. Open browser and enter IP address `127.0.0.2` (the one you assign in virtual host)

Now you site should appear with PHP capabilities.

**UPDATE**

After the latest comment i add here a way to send emails via localhost.

Use a PHP library to send mails from email address of your domain provider:

1. Download [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
2. Copy the ZIP contents into a separate directory in BootstrapLandinPage. For example: `lib/PHPMailer`
3. Add these lines to the top of you process.php

   `require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';`

   `require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';`

   `require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';`

   4. Add the [example snippet](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#a-simple-example) on the documentation page where you downloaded the package and ajust to your needs.

Alternatively for local mailing:

1. Download [hmailserver](https://www.hmailserver.com/download)
2. Install it following their [tutorial](https://www.hmailserver.com/documentation/v5.6/?page=howto_install)
3. Navigate to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file and open it as administrator
4. Add following line:
   `127.0.0.1       localhost localhost.com`
5. Add user example@localhost.com to your hmailserver
6. Configure mail account in your mailing app using:

   `Username: example@localhost.com`

   `Password: your_password`

   `IMAP/SMTP Server: localhost`

**UPDATE 2**

This would be your PHP code using PHPMailer:

```
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

$error_msg = array();
$success_msg = array();
$data = '';

// prevent warnings or errors from displaying, else you won't get proper json result
ini_set('display_errors',0);

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $error_msg['name'] = "Name is required";
    } else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Zא-ת ]*$/",$name)) {
            $error_msg['name'] = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        }
    }


    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $error_msg['email'] = "Email is required";
    } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $error_msg['email'] = "Invalid email format";
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
        $error_msg['phone'] = "Phone is required";
    } else {
        $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!preg_match("/^(\d[\s-]?)?[\(\[\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\)\]\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$/i",$phone)) {
            $error_msg['phone'] = "Invalid phone number";
        }
    }
    if (empty($_POST["subject"])) {
        $error_msg['subject'] = "Subject is required";
    }
    if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
        $error_msg['message'] = "Message is required";
    }

    if (empty($_POST["subject"])) {
        $subject = "";
    } else {
        $subject = test_input($_POST["subject"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
        $message = "";
    } else {
        $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
    }


    if(!empty($error_msg)) {
        $data = array('error'=>$error_msg);
        outputJson($data);
    } else { // note that $lastname_error does not exists
        $message_body = '';
        unset($_POST['submit']);
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
            $message_body .=  "$key: $value\n";
        }

        $to = 'xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com';
        $subjectm = 'Contact Form Submit';

        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
        try {
            //Server settings
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
            $mail->isSMTP();
            $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
            $mail->Username = 'some_user@gmail.com';
            $mail->Password = 'some_password';
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
            $mail->Port = 465;

            //Recipients
            $mail->setFrom('some_user@gmail.com', 'Your name');
            $mail->addAddress($email, $name);

            //Content
            $mail->isHTML(true);
            $mail->Subject = 'Contact Form Submit';
            $mail->Body    = $message;
            $mail->AltBody = preg_replace( "/\n\s+/", "\n", rtrim(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($message))) ); // For clients that do not support html / "spam control"

            $mail->send();

            $data = array('success'=>'Message sent, thank you for contacting us!');
            outputJson($data);

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $data = array('mail_error'=>'Could not send email');
            outputJson($data);
            //echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo; // Debug message that you can see in network tab in web developer browser extension
        }

        $name = $email = $phone = $message = $subject = '';

    }

}
// return data in json format
function outputJson($data) {
    // output json that you can parse with jquery
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
}
function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Hi again :-) I followed the steps exactly as you described below, but something is not right , because when entering 127.0.0.2 in my IP adress I got Object not found!...                                                                       
 Error 404
127.0.0.2
Apache/2.4.25 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/7.1.1 .I passed my httpd-vhosts.conf code   to https://pastebin.com/HBj1TkTC , so you can have a quick look , maybe I did something wrong (when I open my index.html ... the ip adressI got is file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/BootstrapLandinPage/index.html) ,should I include file:/// ? Please advise, TNX

Comment: Your path is incorrect. `DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/BootstrapLandinPage/index.html //` should be `DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/BootstrapLandinPage/` and the second one `<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/BootstrapLandinPage/index.html">` should be  `<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/BootstrapLandinPage">`. After editing
 and saving, don't forget to restart apache. You should then finally see your website by entering 127.0.0.2 into your browser.

Comment: So there was a small progress , I succeed to open  my website by entering 127.0.0.2 in the browser after I adapted the code to what you told me , but now I got next error: 127.0.0.2 says  Could not send mail  as an alarm . What can be the issue now? Thanks for your patience :)

Comment: Ok, so you say the alert window pops because my script won't send email since I am on localhost ? What if I'll upload my website to the air ,will it work (send the form and show the success message?) .Or do I need to follow all the steps as you suggested in your last update anyway  in order to make it work ?

Comment: Yes exactly. If you can send mails after uploading depends on you provider and if they allow mail(). It is generally a better idea though to use proper IMAP mails. For example PHPMailer, with an email address, email password, ingoing (imap) outgoing (smtp) server. If you do not have an email address that you can use, you could setup a gmail account.

Comment: Ok understood, ill upload the website in few days and I'll see what happens, but meanwhile is there a way to show success message after I submit a form  ?

Comment: So I tried to set PHPmailer on localhost anyway just to understand the process, all the steps you described are pretty simple up to number 4. A bit confused regarding where I should include the example snippet. What do you mean by the documentation page?

Comment: I added the php code with PHPMailer to my answer. You can show whatever success message you want. A jquery alert popup, simple javascript alert, showing an alert div container, colored text etc. whatever you like :) You will have to adapt your javascript ajax function to your needs. Right after `success: function(data) {`

Comment: Hey :) So I finally uploaded the site to a server , everything works so thank you again. The only issue I am trying to figure out is how to show success message in a new div the same place form div is after the form submission.   Now it pops after I press submit next to the submit button,also the form stays filled  and wont clear the fields .